# Getting a File size, File extension and allocating it to a new folder under a different name in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I'm writing my own log on changer in C/C++ trough DEV C++

It is supposed to change the image on the background of the login screen but I want it to get the image from the user input, check if it's under 245KB and if it's a *.jpeg file.

Ideally it would be done in the set_image() function.
Here's my current code if it does any help to you:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<conio.c>
#include<stdlib.h>

int patch(){
    system("cls");
    system("regedit /s ./src/patch.reg");
    system("md %windir%/system/oobe/info/backgrounds");
    gotoxy(12,35);
    printf("Patch Successful!");
    return 0;
}

int unpatch(){
    system("regedit /s ./src/unpatch.reg");
    system("rd /q %windir%/system/oobe/info/backgrounds");
    gotoxy(12,35);
    printf("Unpatch Successful!");
    return 0;
}

int set_image(){


}


main(){
       int i;
       system("cls");
       gotoxy(10,1);
       printf("LOGON CHANGER V0.1");
       gotoxy(30,10);
       printf("1 - Patch");
       gotoxy(30,11);
       printf("2 - Unpatch");
       gotoxy(30,12);
       printf("3 - Set Image");
       gotoxy(15,25);
       printf("Insert your option");
       gotoxy(35,25);
       scanf("%i",&i);
       switch(i){
                 case 1:
                      patch();
                      break;
                 case 2:
                      unpatch();
                      break;
                 case 3:
                      set_image();
                      break;
                 default:
                         system("cls");
                         gotoxy(35,12);
                         printf("Not a valid input, try again ;)");
                         Sleep(3000);
                         main();
       }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but this is not C++. *The function main shall not be used within a program.*

Comment: Why don't you google for how to do each of those independently on Windows, and post here only when you have actual code that attempts each of the points you discuss and have a specific problem we can help you with?

Comment: Those `system` calls would be much better replaced with actual API calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this in C++ with a handful of standard library classes and utilities. The example below should get your started. You'll want to change the error handling and modify it to suit your specific needs.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

bool set_image(
    const std::string& inPathname,
    const std::string& outPathname,
    size_t maxSize)
{
    // Validate file extension
    size_t pos = inPathname.rfind('.');
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Get the file extension, convert to lowercase and make sure it's jpg
    std::string ext = inPathname.substr(pos);
    std::transform(ext.begin(), ext.end(), ext.begin(), std::tolower);
    if (ext != ".jpg")
    {
        return false;
    }

    // open input file
    std::ifstream in(inPathname, std::ios::binary);
    if (!in.is_open())
    {
        return false;
    }

    // check length
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    if (in.tellg() > maxSize)
    {
        return false;
    }
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // open output file
    std::ofstream out(outPathname, std::ios::binary);
    if (!out.is_open())
    {
        return false;
    }

    // copy file
    std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<char>(in),
        std::istream_iterator<char>(),
        std::ostream_iterator<char>(out));

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Oblivious thank you :)